# How to call a python script from iOS

Tags: python, ios, apache

I'm making a backend for my iOS game, and trying to figure out how to register new users. I have the python script below on a apache server. How do I call the script from objective-c? And how do I send a JSON respons back?

Thanks

```
def createNewUser(username):

    new_user = {

        "username" : username,
        "usernameLower" : username.lower(), 
        "score" : 0
    }

    user = db.users.find_one({"usernameLower" : username.lower()})

    if user:
        print "Username taken"
        return False
    else:
        # Create new user 
        db.users.insert(new_user, safe=True);
        print "Successfully inserted document: %s" % new_user
        print "New user"
        return True
```

Comment: What did you try ? AFNetworking will be a solution for you or just use NSJSONSerialization + NSURLConnection

Comment: I got the iOS side covered, but new to python and have no idea how where to begin. Is it some kind of HTTP python code I need? Do I call the python file like standarn php files, e.g http://server.com/file.php?username=myName?

Comment: Yes you have to do HTTP request with JSON inside.

Comment: ok... Is it a REST api i need to build in python in order to make it communicate with the ios app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you build a RESTful service using Django.

If you are unfamiliar with REST you can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Django is a powerful framework for python to build websites and RESTful API's. You can read about it here: http://django-rest-framework.org/

It offers a simple and powerful way to set up your service, and converting your data to JSON very easily, and export it to whoever interacts with your API. It is also possible to use Django Auth app to setup API users, to improve security if you only want yourself to be able to interact with the API. Furthermore Django has a huge community and has extensive documentation and lots of tutorials and code snippets for beginners.

Once you got your RESTful service set up, you can begin using your backend from Obj-C. If you have no experience accessing RESTful services from an iOS application, I can highly recommend the framework RestKit. It is very well documented, and works very well for communicating with RESTful services from within an iOS app.

You can read about RestKit here:
http://restkit.org/

Hope it helps